# Achieving Smooth Transition Animation with Consistent Button Position in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I have a Flutter application with an AnimatedSwitcher widget that transitions between two containers. The transition works well, but I want the button outside the animated widget to follow the transition smoothly without jumping.

Here is the current code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isOn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isOn = !_isOn;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Toggle'),
        ),
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          child: _isOn
              ? Container(
                  key: const ValueKey('On'),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  child: const Text('On'),
                )
              : Container(
                  key: const ValueKey('Off'),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 500,
                  width: 300,
                  child: const Text('Off'),
                ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, I have a MyApp widget with a MyWidget StatefulWidget. MyWidget contains an AnimatedSwitcher that transitions between two containers based on a toggle button.

I would like to achieve a smooth transition animation (e.g., fade, rotation) between the two containers while ensuring that the outside button maintains a consistent position (e.g., height) throughout the animation.

Here I place 2 widget with a specific height but my real app have different height possible.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you wrap your AnimatedSwitcher in an Expanded? So it always takes the possible height?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I would need the minimum height , might be a flexible and the example is not exhaustive but I would like this in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AnimatedSize will keep the button on top, but the alignment needs to change `topCenter` from default `center`

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isOn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isOn = !_isOn;
              });
            },
            child: const Text('Toggle'),
          ),
          AnimatedSize(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: _isOn
                ? Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: 300,
                    width: 300,
                    child: const Text('On'),
                  )
                : Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 500,
                    width: 300,
                    child: const Text('Off'),
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**v0** : You can `AnimatedContainer`, it will the animations.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool _isOn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _isOn = !_isOn;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Toggle'),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
            // key: const ValueKey('On'),
            color: _isOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
            height: _isOn ? 300 : 500,
            width: 300,
            child: Text(_isOn ? 'On' : 'Off'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but I mention that both widget have unpredicted height. Might be I should build both to do so but I wonder if its possible in a easier way.

Comment: AnimationBuilder might work, let me see if there are any implicit widget work for your case.

Comment: ok, something with AnimatedSize, is it ok if the animation start from top?

Comment: I did not get your question. If the container is centered the animation would be bottom and top and the upper toggle button will slide down if the widget is smaller or slide on the top if bigger.

Comment: Ok, let me update the snippet and share the feedback if it works for you.

Comment: Yes adding a AnimatedSize as parent of the AnimatedSwitcher do the job. Thanks